# Android SQLite won't execute onUpgrade()

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-update

I'm trying to add some columns to my SQLite database. I keep having the following error: 
 `no such column: n_livello` (eg. the new column I'm adding) 
 and the app installation fails with `timeout`. 
It seems that onUpgrade() method is never called. 
This is my code:

```
public class Main extends Activity {

    Context context;
    DBHelper db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    context = this.getApplicationContext(); 
    db = new DBHelper(context);

    }

}

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

   public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "geko";
   static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

   public DBHelper(Context context){
      super(context, DATABASE_NAME , null, DATABASE_VERSION);
   }  

   @Override
   public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

      String CREATE_FRA_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+ FRA_TABLE_NAME + " ("
              + FRA_COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
              + FRA_COLUMN_USERNAME + " TEXT, "
              + FRA_COLUMN_NUM_LIVELLO + "INTEGER, "
              + FRA_COLUMN_LIVELLO + " TEXT, "
              + FRA_COLUMN_TEMPO + " TEXT, "
              + FRA_COLUMN_DATA_PARTITA + " TEXT,"
              + FRA_COLUMN_INVIATO + " INTEGER)";

              db.execSQL(CREATE_FRA_TABLE);

      String CREATE_ING_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+ ING_TABLE_NAME + " ("
              + ING_COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
              + ING_COLUMN_USERNAME + " TEXT, "
              + ING_COLUMN_NUM_LIVELLO + "INTEGER, "
              + ING_COLUMN_LIVELLO + " TEXT, "
              + ING_COLUMN_TEMPO + " TEXT, "
              + ING_COLUMN_DATA_PARTITA + " TEXT,"
              + ING_COLUMN_INVIATO + " INTEGER)";

              db.execSQL(CREATE_ING_TABLE);
   }

   public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
       db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ FRA_TABLE_NAME);
       db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ ING_TABLE_NAME);
       onCreate(db);
   }
}
```

Thanks for the help.

[EDIT]
I checked and onUpgrade() is not called. Obviously I get the error when I try to make a query that concernes the new fields I'm trying to add. Maybe I am declaring the DBHelper class the wrong way...
 I'm adding the code in the main activity where I instance the `DBHelper`.

Comment: Have you increased your database version?

Comment: Did you increment your db version number?

Comment: Also: what an extreme way of performing database upgrades. Isn't it more appropriate to use `ALTER TABLE` instead of removing table with all the data?

Comment: Yes, my DATABASE_VERSION was 1, now it's 2...

Comment: After editing the table structure you increased your Version huh?

Comment: @AlexSemeniuk usually yes, but in this case I made a lot of changes to fields and datatypes and was more simple to drop the existing database.

Comment: "It seems that onUpgrade() method is never called."

Is this an assumption or have you put a breakpoint there and debugged it (or logged some debug message or ...)?

Comment: Uninstall your app and re run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting `@Override` before your `onUpgrade`

Here's a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94361/when-do-you-use-javas-override-annotation-and-why) to an SO question that covers when and why calling `@Override` is important.

Comment: Um, this could not have been the problem.

Comment: But OP was missing an @Override call before his `onUpgrade`. Wouldn't that have constituted to his `onUpgrade` not getting called and invoked properly?

Comment: @Astatine0936 If there was a problem with the overriding, there would have been a compile-time error rather than a runtime one. `@Override` annotations are generally good but not strictly required.

Comment: I see, in which case why did it suddenly work then ? What could have cause `onUpgrade` to not be called properly? 

Also just to be clear I'm not trying to argue with you, in case that's how it's coming across ( relaying intent through text isn't easy ). I want to understand just as much as the OP what the problem was, it's cause and solution as I am just learning myself.

Comment: See my answer and the linked question for OP's problem, solution and further information.

Answer (score 2):

Add a space between the column name and datatype here:

```
+ ING_COLUMN_NUM_LIVELLO + "INTEGER, "
```

Repeat for both tables.

Finally either increment the database version or uninstall your app so that `onCreate()` gets run again, either via `onUpgrade()` or directly. [When is SQLiteOpenHelper onCreate() / onUpgrade() run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881992/when-is-sqliteopenhelper-oncreate-onupgrade-run)

Comment: Thank you, I didn't notice that!

Answer (score 1):

In the constructor of your class extending SQLiteOpenHelper increase the version of your DB
for instance:

```
public MyDBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
}
```

Where DATABASE_VERSION should be an integer with a value greater than the one you used in the previous version of your DB schema